# How can i sort select2 results by specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I want to sort below Options by First Character.
e.g. if i search 'banana' then all 4 options will search with select2 but i want 'Sbanana1' first.

So is there any option that I sort select2 results by "S"(specific) Character,
so starting from 's' option will display first.

```
<button type=button>Sort Options</button>
<select class='whatever'>
<option value='Banana'>Banana1</option>
    <option value='Hello'>Banana2</option>        
    <option value='Sugar Cane'>SBanana1</option>
    <option value='Palm Oil'>SBanana2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: use custom matcher https://select2.org/searching

Comment: i tried with that but not able to find solution.

Comment: which version of select 2 are you using

Comment: select2 version 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Select2 options API v4.0 - sort

```js
$('.whatever').select2({
  sorter: function(data) {
    /* Sort data using lowercase comparison */

    return data.sort(function(a, b) {
      a = a.text.toLowerCase();
      b = b.text.toLowerCase();
      
      if (a[0] == 's' && b[0] == 's') {
        return compare(a, b)
      } else if (a[0] == 's') {
        return -1;
      } else if (b[0] == 's') {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return compare(a, b)
      }
    });
  }
});

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" integrity="sha256-xqxV4FDj5tslOz6MV13pdnXgf63lJwViadn//ciKmIs=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha256-FA14tBI8v+/1BtcH9XtJpcNbComBEpdawUZA6BPXRVw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="whatever">
    <option value="Banana">Banana1</option>
    <option value="Hello">Banana2</option>
    <option value="Sugar Cane">SBanana1</option>
    <option value="Palm Oil">SBanana2</option>
</select>
```

Using Select2 options API v3.x - sortResults

```js
$('.whatever').select2({
  sortResults: function(data) {
    /* Sort data using lowercase comparison */

    return data.sort(function(a, b) {
      a = a.text.toLowerCase();
      b = b.text.toLowerCase();
      
      if (a[0] == 's' && b[0] == 's') {
        return compare(a, b)
      } else if (a[0] == 's') {
        return -1;
      } else if (b[0] == 's') {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return compare(a, b)
      }
    });
  }
});

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.css" integrity="sha256-ijlUKKj3hJCiiT2HWo1kqkI79NTEYpzOsw5Rs3k42dI=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js" integrity="sha256-7A2MDY2eGSSUvgfbuH1IdzYk8qkEd3uzwiXADqPDdtY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="whatever">
      <option value="Banana">Banana1</option>
      <option value="Hello">Banana2</option>
      <option value="Sugar Cane">SBanana1</option>
      <option value="Palm Oil">SBanana2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: when i am using this it can not scroll to top when there are more options. how can i do it?

Comment: reproduce the issue in fiddle and share

Comment: for eg. i have 10 options s1 to s10, now if i select s10 first, then if i select again s1 then its not focusing on first option, i mean not scrolling to top